# writing text file from URL

Tags: java, file-writing

I have a problem about writing text file. I can read from URL but I want to write this information to the text file. Below is the input that I can get from URL. When I tried to write them to the file, I just saw the last line in the text file gear4/prog_index.m3u8 Can you help me to solve this problem

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=200000
gear1/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=311111
gear2/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=484444
gear3/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=737777
gear4/prog_index.m3u8



public void CreateFile()
{
    File master=new File("Master Playlist.txt");
    try {
        FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(master, false);
        BufferedWriter bufferedwriter= new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        bufferedwriter.write(read);
        bufferedwriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public String Connect()
{
    try {
        URL url=new URL(newlink);
        URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        DataInputStream input=new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        while((read=input.readLine())!=null)
        {
            CreateFile();
            System.out.println(read);
```

Comment: It seems like part of your code example is missing.

Comment: `CreateFile();` - I doubt you want to create a file for every line. Also, method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Break the problem down into two parts. 1) Learn how to write to a file. Just take a simple string and make sure you can write it a few times to a file. 2) Read a file using a URL. Once you have both of those pieces done separately, you should be able to merge them together and get something working. If you are still stuck after doing this, come back and post a new question that is more specific to the problem. Please read the help article on [asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to create a text file that includes whole lines. But I could not figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'append' and not 'overwrite' the current file so the old data will not be erased . change the flag to true :

```
FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(master, false); // overwrite
FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(master, true); // append
```

Comment: Thank you, that is totally what I want to do. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The whole structure of your code is wrong. You don't want to keep creating a new File and opening and closing the file for every line of data.

You want to:

1. open the file once before the while loop
2. in the while loop you write the data to the file
3. after the while loop you close the file.